# JMeter http choose different url variable

Tags: jmeter

I want to test a resource that gets a token in the URL.
for example:   `localhost:8080/api/{TOKEN}/function`

I want JMeter to choose from a list of 4 different tokens. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible given JMeter is open source.

If you have i.e. 4 [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) containing tokens like:

[image: User Defined Variables]

You can get a random one for the each request using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination like:

```
${__V(TOKEN_${__Random(1,4,)})}
```

[image: Random Variable demo]

So you can change "Path" of the HTTP Request Sampler to look like:

```
/api/${__V(TOKEN_${__Random(1,4,)})}/function
```

and that should be it. See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks, can you be more specific with the directions:  Where do I put the random string? I add a new random variable? new user defined varialbe?

Comment: you can replace these `lorem`, `ipsum`, `dolor` and `sit` with your actual tokens in the User Defined Variables and that should be it.